# IOS GameKit - Is there a way to force the creation of a totally new turn-based match through "findMatchForRequest"?

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

According to Apple's documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

"This method may either create a new match or it may place the player into an existing match that needs a new player to advance the match further. "

Is there a way to force the creation of a new match without letting the player join an already created one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always request a new one when the retrieved match is not new by checking the cond

```
match.matchData.length == 0
```

But if you do such a thing according to dummy principles of game center you will never be able to match 2 players. Because if user hasn't done any moves, other players will not be able to join the game, and you will be creating new fresh games all the time.

One way to surpass this is to add an empty turn by the first player and the other players will be able to connect now so after then you can decide which player starts or let them select game settings etc. But I didn't check this with apple's guidelines it might be a rejection reason or so.

Comment: If i request a new game, i'm not sure if i will not keep joining the game already in progress over and over. But i think i managed to incorporate some logic to circumvent this, thanks :)

Comment: im glad if you made use of my answer anyhow:)

Comment: Game center invitations are not working this days, I dont know what´s going on with game center SandBox server. I hope that your issue it is coming becuase of that.